# iphone игнорирует required в input html

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, required

При нажатии на кнопку «Отправить» в форме, iPhone игнорирует обязательные поля `input` с атрибутом `required` и отправляет форму, как исправить? [image: пример того как должно быть]

Comment: Пользоваться кастомной валидацией заполнения. Емнип, айфоны(ios safari) не умеют в required. Проверять все поля ввода, у которых есть атрибут `required`, если что-то не заполнено, выкидывать там свой тултип.

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/#toc-safari

Answer (score 1):

Это не поддерживается в iphone - http://caniuse.com/#search=required

Только через JS:

```
if (document.getElementById('input').value.trim() === '') {
   // show error, don't send the form
}
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS Safari 10.2- имеет соответствующий баг. В версии 10.3 исправлено.

Баг: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=28649
Источник: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

Как исправить? Проверять форму скриптом перед отправкой.